# list threshold value exceeded ..causes problem in dropdown cascading using SpServices?

Tags: list, spservices

I have list Skill Endorsement.

when i select Employee from drop down,

Project Drop downs should populate.

both Employee and Project are look up fields in Project Allocations and  Skill Endorsements.

i used SPService CascadingDropdown JQuery for Project Allocations to filter Project Dropdown based on Employee Selected.

earlier everything use to work correctly.

but recently Project Drop down doesn't populate at all .

is it because Project Allocation List view Threshold exceeded (5000)???

or because of some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite likely the issue.

If you are using sharepoint online this is a hard limit and Microsoft will block any operation that involves more than 5000 items. If you have an on premise environment you can increase this limit, just speak to your administrator.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..this project is made by some one else and i joined recently to work on it..i knw about increasing the limit through central admin..any other solutions?

Comment: No problem. Please up vote if this has been helpful. Happy to assist further if you need clarification

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the list threshhold to higher value?

The work around is to "Override the list view threshold for an individual list by setting the SPList.EnableThrottling property to false.

```
  private static void DisbaleListThrottling()
        {
           using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://YourSiteNameHere.com/TeamSite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList spList = spWeb.Lists["MyList1"];
                    spList.EnableThrottling = false;
                    spList.Update();
                }
           }
        }
```

You can also use powershell:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://whateverWeb

$list = $web.Lists[“List Title”]

$list.enablethrottling = $false

$lst.update()
```